# Firebase Unable to fetch the CLI MOTD and remote config

Tags: firebase, visual-studio-code, google-cloud-functions

when trying to firebase deploy, getting this

`!  Unable to fetch the CLI MOTD and remote config.`

and then it stops with:

`Error: An unexpected error has occurred.`

Anyone an idea?

It worked before, I didn't change anything. Windows 10, VSCode.

Comment: Sounds like something you should [raise as an issue](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-tools/issues). It's unlikely anybody here can help

Comment: I'll add that I've been having this issue recently. But you should definitely still create an issue on the firebase-tools repo.

Comment: If you have a VPN try to connect/disconnect before login. I had that same issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

run `npm install -g firebase-tools`

Answer (score 3):

Try to logout from firebase and then login again

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: It's correct answer for me.

~~~
firebase logout
firebase login
~~~

Comment: It worked for me. Firebase CLI somehow changed the way login used to work.

Answer (score 0):

As [Danny Menocs](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2213798/danny-mencos) says, I was trying to upload a flutter web project to firebase but had forgotten I had left my VPN on.  Turned it off and connected fine.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are in your firebase functions folder before running the deploy command.

Answer (score 0):

For me it was my company's firewall which prevented me from deploying the content.